# Не могу получить все значения формы в laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Доброе утро, у меня проблема возникла.Не могу получить все  значения формы в laravel.

Это моя форма:
{

```
!! Form::open(['route'=>['store']]) !!}
<h1 class="popup__title">Добавить продукт</h1>
<p class="popup__subtitle">Артикул</p>
<input type="text" class="popup__input form-control" placeholder="Артикул" name="article"  value="{{old('article')}}">
<p class="popup__subtitle">Название</p>
<input type="text" class="popup__input form-control" placeholder="Название" name="name"  value="{{old('name')}}">
<p class="popup__subtitle">Статус</p>
<select id="disabledSelect" class="popup__input form-select" name="status"  value="{{old('name')}}">
        <option>available</option>
        <option>unavailable</option>
      </select>
      <h1 class="popup__title">Атрибуты</h1>
<div class="poput__double-input">
<div class="mb-3 popup__input popup__input_double-input">
<label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="popup__subtitle">Название</label>
     <input type="text" id="disabledTextInput" class="popup__input popup__input_double-input form-control" placeholder="Disabled input" name="atribut-name"  value="{{old('atribut-name')}}">
</div>
<div class="popup__input popup__input_double-input mb-3">
<label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="popup__subtitle">Значение</label>
     <input type="text" id="disabledTextInput" class="popup__input popup__input_double-input form-control" placeholder="Название" name="atribut-value"  value="{{old('atribut-value')}}">
</div>
     </div>
     <div class="poput__double-input">
<div class="popup__input popup__input_double-input mb-3">
<label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="popup__subtitle">Название</label>
     <input type="text" id="disabledTextInput" class="popup__input popup__input_double-input form-control" placeholder="Название">
</div>
<div class="popup__input popup__input_double-input mb-3">
<label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="popup__subtitle">Значение</label>
     <input type="text" id="disabledTextInput" class="popup__input popup__input_double-input form-control" placeholder="Значение">
</div>
     </div>
    
 <p class="popup__subtitle">+ Добавить атрибут</p>
 <button  class="btn btn-primary">Добавить</button>
 {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Данные не приходят с этой части.

```
<div class="poput__double-input">
<div class="mb-3 popup__input popup__input_double-input">
<label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="popup__subtitle">Название</label>
     <input type="text" id="disabledTextInput" class="popup__input popup__input_double-input form-control" placeholder="Disabled input" name="atribut-name"  value="{{old('atribut-name')}}">
</div>
<div class="popup__input popup__input_double-input mb-3">
<label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="popup__subtitle">Значение</label>
     <input type="text" id="disabledTextInput" class="popup__input popup__input_double-input form-control" placeholder="Название" name="atribut-value"  value="{{old('atribut-value')}}">
</div>
     </div>
     <div class="poput__double-input">
<div class="popup__input popup__input_double-input mb-3">
<label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="popup__subtitle">Название</label>
     <input type="text" id="disabledTextInput" class="popup__input popup__input_double-input form-control" placeholder="Название">
</div>
<div class="popup__input popup__input_double-input mb-3">
<label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="popup__subtitle">Значение</label>
     <input type="text" id="disabledTextInput" class="popup__input popup__input_double-input form-control" placeholder="Значение">
</div>
     </div>
```

Это то, что приходит, когда запрашиваю все данные из формы:
array:4 [▼

```
  "_token" => "ZnF3o45gzJc8JSfIEYG6oH5Jq8pAFhk538MRi1b3"
  "article" => "reeee22"
  "name" => "перчатка"
  "status" => "available"
]
```

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: У остальных input указан `id="disabledTextInput"` (id для элемента на странице должен быть уникальный, кстати). По имени атрибута `id` можно предположить, что где-то срабатывает js-код, который задает этим `input` атрибут `disabled`, так ли это?

Comment: @Molod, Спасибо, за помощь. Я просто name="nameAtr" в input забыл прописать.Теперь все работает)